# Variable substitution on left hand side of assignment - PowerShell

Tags: variables, powershell

I am trying to extract the value of a variable on the left-hand side of an assignment statement to use as a new variable in PowerShell v4.0. A brief example follows:

```
    $ptypeCtr = $ptypeCtr + 1; 
    $prow = ('$partyRow' + $ptypeCtr);
    "$prow"  += "case_ref=" + $key;
```

This does not work and throws an exception stating the following:

```
At line:3 char:1
+ "$prow" = "case_ref=" +key;
+ ~~~~~~~
```

The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept 
assignments, such as a variable or a property.

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidLeftHandSide
```

I have also tried using `$($prow)` and `$("$prow")` but this just still returns the same error message.

What I was hoping to achieve was that the `$prow` variable would be evaluated as `$partyRow1` and the be assigned the value `"case_ref=123"`.

Has anybody got any suggestions or ideas about how to achieve this in Powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, I think this might do it:

```
Set-Variable -Name $prow -Value "case_ref=$key"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, it is very much appreciated. I have tried your suggestion but it seems that it has created the variable with 2 $$ e.g. $$partyRow1. When you enter in either $partyRow1 or indeed $$partyRow1, it does not return any values. It's strange because when you look at the variables in PPlus, you can see the variable $partyRow="case_ref=123" but I cannot get access to it.

Comment: It has the extra $ because you're making it part of the literal name here:  $prow = ('$partyRow' + $ptypeCtr) .   Change that to: $prow = ('partyRow' + $ptypeCtr) then use the Set-Variable to use that as the new variable name.